# How to check list of child is drive from base class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

```
public  class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get;  set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }p
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }}
}

public class A : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set;}
    public virtual List<childClassOFA> Contacts { get; set; } //childClassOFA IS Also drive from BaseEntity
}

Type myType = entity.GetType();

foreach (var entityInFo in entity.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    bool isList = entityInFo.PropertyType != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(entityInFo.PropertyType);
    if (isList == true)
    {
        var list = entityInFo.GetValue(entity.GetType().GetProperty(entityInFo.Name).GetValue(entity, null)) as List<object>;
        if (list != null) {
            var type = list.Select(a => a.GetType()).FirstOrDefault() ;type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEntity));
         }
        //do something
    }
}
```

i need to check that list of childClassOFA drive from BaseEntity or not i have to check weather it belong to the base class or not and also need to get list properties

Comment: The question is unclear. It would also be better to ask one question at a time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also note that a `List<childClassOFA>` is not castable to a `List<Object>`, so your `list` will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the base class of `childClassOFA` is `BaseEntity` with [is operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is). It might look something like this:

```
if (childClassOFAInstance is BaseEntity)
{
    //your logic here
}
```

You can also check out `as` operator, I have issues understanding what you really need to achieve, so maybe it will be better solution for you.